# Solidity Error Address / Address Payable

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain

I'm currently learning solidity programming to create a basic smart contract based on a 2018 tutorial where solidity was using version 4. I'm currently using truffle v5.0.21. I understand that there was an update from "address" to "address payable", but i'm still not able to get it to work after referencing to similar threads. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

**Code for ApprovalContract.sol:**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.18;

contract ApprovalContract {

    address public sender;
    address public receiver;
    address public constant approver = 0xAFXXX;


    function deposit(address _receiver) external payable{
        require(msg.value > 0);
        sender = msg.sender;
        receiver = _receiver;
    }


    function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) {
        return(approver);
    }


    function approve() external{
        require(msg.sender == approver);
        receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

}
```

**Error that comes out on CMD:**

//start of error code

TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".
                receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
                                     ^---------------^

Compilation failed. See above.

//end of error code

Answer (score 2):

That's because `receiver` and `_receiver` need to be payable. I've set an address of the Javascript VM of Remix as the approver.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract ApprovalContract {

    address public sender;
    address payable public receiver;
    address public constant approver = 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c;

    function deposit(address payable _receiver) external payable{
        require(msg.value > 0);
        sender = msg.sender;
        receiver = _receiver;
    }

    function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) {
        return(approver);
    }

    function approve() external{
        require(msg.sender == approver);
        receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```