# TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"

Tags: solidity, truffle-compile

I'm currently trying to test run source code from GitHub based on a 2018 tutorial where solidity was using version 0.5.16. I'm currently using truffle v4.1.14. I understand that there was an update from "address" to "address payable", but I'm still not able to get it to work after referencing to similar threads. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

import "./StringUtils.sol";
import "./Accounts.sol";

/** @title Documents. */
contract Documents {
    
  address payable private owner;
  address public accountsAddress;
  Document payable[] private documents;
  mapping (address => Count) private counts;
  enum DocStatus {Pending, Verified, Rejected}
  mapping (address => uint) balances;
 
  struct Document {
    address requester;
    address verifier;
    string name;
    string description;
    string docAddress;
    DocStatus status;
  }
  
  struct Count {
    uint verified;
    uint rejected;
    uint total;
  }

  event DocumentAdded (address user);
  event DocumentVerified (address user);
  event test (uint test);

function verifyDocument(string memory docAddress, DocStatus status) 
  public 
  payable
  {
    for (uint i=0; i<documents.length; i++) {
      if(StringUtils.equal(documents[i].docAddress, docAddress) && documents[i].verifier == msg.sender && documents[i].status == DocStatus.Pending){
        emit DocumentVerified(msg.sender);
        uint price = Accounts(accountsAddress).getPrice(documents[i].verifier);
        balances[documents[i].verifier] -= price;
        if(status == DocStatus.Rejected){
            counts[documents[i].requester].rejected = counts[documents[i].requester].rejected + 1;
            counts[documents[i].verifier].rejected = counts[documents[i].verifier].rejected + 1;
            // return the ether for rejection
            documents[i].requester.transfer(price);
        }
        if(status == DocStatus.Verified){
            counts[documents[i].requester].verified = counts[documents[i].requester].rejected + 1;
            counts[documents[i].verifier].verified = counts[documents[i].verifier].verified + 1;
            // send ether to verified account
            documents[i].verifier.transfer(price);
        }
        documents[i].status = status;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

** Documents.sol:208:13: TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".
documents[i].requester.transfer(price);
^-----------------------------^ **

Full source code: https://github.com/lionel1702/final-project-RumeelHussain/blob/master/contracts/Documents.sol

Error Log: https://github.com/lionel1702/log/blob/master/emailRegexErrorLog4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change a few more of type `address` to be `address payable`. Namely here:

```
struct Document {
    address requester;
    address verifier;
    string name;
    string description;
    string docAddress;
    DocStatus status;
  }
```

Change into:

```
struct Document {
    address payable requester;
    address payable verifier;
    string name;
    string description;
    string docAddress;
    DocStatus status;
  }
```

Possible also changes needed in other parts of the contracts, but this should fix this immediate issue.

Comment: Another error came through 
`Documents.sol:99:19: TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested.
        verifier: _verifier,
                  ^-------^`

Comment: Thank you so much, I did manage to solve this problem too.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71766/solidity-error-address-address-payable
Everything went well.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the `transfer_address` as `payable` like,

```
payable(transfer_address).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

where transfer_address is the sender's address(msg.sender).

Comment: It quickly fixes something like this `payable(msg.sender)`. Thanks.

Comment: Edited to clarify more about 'transfer_address'.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#address):

> The address type comes in two largely identical flavors:
>
> **address**: Holds a 20 byte value (size of an Ethereum address).
>
> **address payable**: Same as address, but with the additional members transfer and send.
>
> The idea behind this distinction is that address payable is an address you can send Ether to, while you are not supposed to send Ether to a plain address, for example because it might be a smart contract that was not built to accept Ether.

So, in order to send Eth to an address, you need to make it *payable* by:

1. Declaring it as an `address payable`
2. Converting it to an `address payable` using the payable(addr) method